# How to change innerHTML of childNodes in case some childnodes without tags?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

That is my example of problem

```
<div onclick="this.childNodes(0).innerHTML='0';">
1<b>2</b>3<b>4</b>5
</div>
```

as you see, two childnodes ("**2**" and "**4**") are tagged, others are simple text.
The question is how to change innerHTML of tagged and untagged nodes (texts) in sertain div container without touching other nodes/texts?

Comment: Just to be certain: based on your updated question, does that mean you want all five numbers to be replaced with 0?

Comment: But I agree to dig into JQ lib and grab JS code from there, if any of course =)

Comment: @Lorax Yes, I need all childes (children?) to be accessible, but not at once, of course.

Comment: I don't think you *can* access the `innerHTML` of a non-element node; you could access the `textNode`'s `nodeValue` though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essentially, you'll use the `data`(text) property for text nodes (`nodeType` 3) and `innerHTML` otherwise ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yJfQh/)):

```
<div onclick="this.childNodes[0][this.childNodes[0].nodeType === 3 ? 'data' : 'innerHTML'] = '0'">
1<b>2</b>3<b>4</b>5
</div>​
```

[edit] I'm getting really tired of everyone offering *libraries* as solutions when all that's required is a simple explanation of a basic concept, e.g.: text-nodes and element nodes have differing content properties, i.e.: `data` and `innerHTML`.

Comment: problem with linebreaks. when all newlines replaced to <br> - result look awful =) I think its because <br> tag is additional child.

Comment: Well, that and you can't really place a `<br/>` element inside a text-node... you'd get a `HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3`.

Comment: Can I change the type of the childnode? To make it innerHTML accessible?

Comment: No, but you can replace the node with a new node via `replaceChild()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.replaceChild

Comment: I did it =)  var NewText=document.createElement('span'); NewText.innerHTML=this.value.replace(/\n/g,'<br>'); Obj.replaceChild(NewText,Obj.childNodes[0]); and thanx again

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a lib called [Linguigi](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/Linguigi). It would be as easy as

```
new Linguigi(element).eachText(function(text) {
    if(this.parentNode.tagName === 'B') {
        return "BACON";
    }
});
```

which turns the text of all text nodes inside b-tags to "BACON". You get the original content as "text" parameter and could transform that.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kz2jX/

BTW: You should get rid of the inline event handling (`onclick` attribute)

Answer (score 1):

You can cycle through each of the nodes recursively, checking their `nodeType` property in turn and updating the `nodeValue` property with '0' if the node is a text node (indicated by `nodeType == 3`).

Assuming you have this **HTML**:

```
<div onclick="doReplace(this)">
    1<b>2</b>3<b>4</b>5
</div>
```

You can then write a simple replace function that calls itself recursively, like so:

```
window.doReplace = function (rootNode) {
    var children = rootNode.childNodes;
    for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var aChild = children[i];
        if(aChild.nodeType == 3) {
            aChild.nodeValue = '0';
        }
        else {
            doReplace(aChild);
        }
    }
}
```

A working fiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/p9YCn/1/